# After removing an item from p:orderList it's ordering changes

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
var1
var2
var3
```

let's change an order of them

```
var3
var2
var1
```

result is

```
var1
var2
```

I checks that in the backing bean, so if Primefaces orders items only virtualy in view, so is there a way to keep the order of `p:orderList` elements? How to reflect changes after reodering in the backing bean?

update:

```
    <ui:composition>

    <p:orderList id="stack" value="#{expression.list}" 
        var="stackElement" itemLabel="#{stackElement}" itemValue="#{stackElement}" controlsLocation="none" >

        <p:ajax event="reorder" />

        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{stackElement.name}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="width: 4%">
            <p:commandButton update="stack" 
                icon="ui-icon-close" actionListener="#{expression.clear()}">
                <f:param name="selectedElement" value="#{stackElement.id}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>

    </p:orderList>

    </ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `p:ajax event="reorder"` to the `p:orderList` to submit the reordered collection to the server.

Comment: It seems nothing changes. `<p:ajax event="reorder" listener="#{expression.onReorder}" />` only shows the original ordering of list. I checked that in backing bean i.e. the backing bean list does't reflect changes.

Comment: @globalx, it works for me. Post your relevant xhtml and java code. Which PrimeFaces version?

Comment: @globalx, maybe your bean is improperly scoped and gets recreated?

Comment: the ploblem was deeper, now fixed.